# Макарони та вермішель - синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

Вермішель та макарони повні синоніми?

СУМ-20

[Макарони](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=49273&page=1550) *Харчовий продукт у формі трубочок з борошна. //Страва з цього продукту*

[Вермішель](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7509&page=277) *Макаронний виріб у вигляді тонких коротких паличок. // Страва з цього продукту*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [макарони](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8) ([від італ. *maccheroni* «макарони» (одн. — *maccherone*; від середньогр. *μακαρία* «їжа з ячменю»)](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maccheroni#Etymology)) — у формі трубочок;
- [вермішель](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) ([від італ. *vermicelli* «черв'ячки» (одн. — *vermicello*; зменш. від *verme* «черв'як»)](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vermicelli#Etymology)) — у формі порівняно коротких паличок;
- [спагеті](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%96) ([від італ. *spaghetti* «струночки» (одн. — *spaghetto*; зменш. від *spago* «струна»)](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaghetti#Etymology_3)) — у формі довгих паличок.

Разом це називається *[макаронні вироби](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8)* (на багатьох мовах світу — *[pasta](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasta)*). Припускаю, що в розмовній мові будь-який різновид можуть називати скорочено *макаронами*. Хоча не виключаю, що в розмовній мові будь-який різновид можуть називати й *вермішеллю*.